# Can I create a formula to provide a value depending on when a timestamp falls in the day?

Tags: numbers

In column A, I have timestamp values. In a second column, I'd like to have a formula that would return words or strings like "early morning" or "Late afternoon", so that I may count and chart these responses.  What formula am I looking for in Apple's Numbers?

Comment: It's a good idea to provide sample of your timestamp values.

Comment: Is it a UNIX timestamp?  Or just the standard date and time from Numbers insert date?  How are the timestamp values generated?

Comment: So I'm generating these time stamps with a text expander snippet, which I imagine means that it is really being converted via Numbers' standard insert date.

Comment: 2/11/2016 12:00:00 AM  Like that?

Comment: @bjbk yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a normal Numbers Date/Time `2/11/2016 12:00:00 AM`, then a simple `IF()` statement can be used combined with the `HOUR` function.

`=IF( HOUR ( A2 ) < 12, "Good Morning", "Good Afternoon")`

To add more than just 2 options, nest your `IF` statement.

`=IF(HOUR(A3) < 5,"Early",IF(HOUR(A3) < 12,"Morning",IF(HOUR(A3) < 17,"afternoon",IF(HOUR(A3) < 20,"evening","night"))))`

Numbers will return the first TRUE value.

[image: Formula Sample]